# DbUp and script directory

Tags: sql-server, deployment

I'm using [DbUp](http://dbup.github.io/), starting from the example I've created a C# program. The example suggest me to put all scripts under *Scripts* directory. Ok, this is done but, when script number will grow up that directory will be such a big mess.

I would organize that directories with version number. For instance

- 1.0.0 (directory)

  - CS001 - baseline.sql
- 1.0.1 (directory)

  - CS001 - alter x table.sql
  - CS002 - create y procedure.sql
- 1.1.0 (directory)

  - CS001 - create view z.sql

Obviously, code would take the script in an ordered manner. How can I do that? Where I found documentation and other examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbUp automatically takes the filenames in alphnumeric order, so prefix them with a version or timestamp.

Comment: It is actually ordered in lexicographical fashion.

Comment: @Simon.Ponder I have no idea what that even means?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Answer (score 1):

DbUp takes the path into consideration and stores it in SchemaVersions. You organize exactly as you have asked the question.

Comment: This is the correct answer, although an example would be probably make it easier to understand